# how to use mechanize as current real firefox browser?

Tags: python, firefox, mechanize

I log in a SNS website with my own accounts in real firefox browser.( it needs verify code! )
and now I want to do something with mechanize in python. I imported all cookies that current firefox browser kept to a MozillaCookieJar instance called "cj", and then created a browser `br=Mechanize.Browser()`, set its cookiejar `br.set_cookiejar(cj)`, but when I use it to open the SNS website again in python `br.open(site)` it told me I did'nt log in yet, are there some key steps that I missed?

best regards!

Comment: is the use of Mechanize a constraint for you? If not, consider using [Selenium WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) to directly automate Firefox you already know it is working with your website

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use: Selenium or [Spynner](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/spynner) if mechanize isn't enough.